# Javascript Modal Popup with URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a popup method like its used on https://www.behance.net/ - when user click's on a project, a popup opens and the user can see the URL in the main window. How can I achieve that e.g. what must I do? Is it pure javascript? because it seems that behance is not using any plugin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what you have tried???

Comment: @Manwal I tried to use the `maginific popup`-plugin and to do some `window.location`-method, but no luck...

Comment: Then you can use custom popup or Bootstrap Model

Comment: Besides the popup which can be solved by plugins listed in answers you should get familiar with HTML5 additions to browser `History`: `pushState` and `popState` methods - this is how you change the URL without loading a new document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twitter bootstrap 3.0. Its providing modal popup and this one is mobile and ipad friendly as it automatically adjust with screen resolution.

Refer http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to achieve this: use a plugin!

- [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)
- [Bootstrap Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
- [choose your plugin](http://www.jquery4u.com/windows/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/)

Comment: None of those doesnt seem to provide URL functions?

Comment: e.g. Bootstrap `If a remote URL is provided, content will be loaded one time via jQuery's load method and injected into the .modal-content div. If you're using the data-api, you may alternatively use the href attribute to specify the remote source. An example of this is shown below:`